# How to change background colour of vaadin 8 combobox's dropdown items?

Tags: css, combobox, styles, vaadin, vaadin8

I am working with vaadin 8, and I have a com.vaadin.ui.ComboBox called "contacts" which is filled with a number of string-items. Whenever I click into the combobox, the items are displayed as a dropdown after I hit the space bar. The background against which the dropdown is displayed is transparent, and I would like to dye it blue. The F12-tools seem to be of no avail to find out which class I have to style. So what can I do to change the background-color of the pane on which the dropdown items are displayed?

Answer (score 2):

Use the class `.gwt-MenuItem` for the dropdown entries. See https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-combobox/#components.combobox.css